# Random errors in SSRS Log "The report server cannot open a connection to the report server database."

Tags: reporting-services

My SSRS runs snapshot in the morning. I noticed some of the reports are not snapshoting once in a while.

I found following error which is random daily for the difrerent report.

The report server cannot open a connection to the report server database.

library!WindowsService_28!1d168!02/23/2018-05:47:42:: e ERROR: Throwing Microsoft.ReportingServices.Library.ReportServerDatabaseUnavailableException: , Microsoft.ReportingServices.Library.ReportServerDatabaseUnavailableException: The report server cannot open a connection to the report server database. A connection to the database is required for all requests and processing. ---> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Connection Timeout Expired.  The timeout period elapsed during the post-login phase.  The connection could have timed out while waiting for server to complete the login process and respond; Or it could have timed out while attempting to create multiple active connections.  The duration spent while attempting to connect to this server was - [Pre-Login] initialization=0; handshake=11; [Login] initialization=0; authentication=0; [Post-Login] complete=16573;  ---> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: The wait operation timed out
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---

Thank you,

Kalpesh

Answer (score 0):

Possible reasons could be a network disconnection, blocking due to a firewall or antivirus or possible overload of the database server. What time does it occur? What processes are active at that time? Does the task manager at the database server show any performance flags? Does it happen everyday? Since when are you facing this issue? Was there a software update in the interim? More information will be required to troubleshoot.

Comment: Hi Prasad, Thank You. My report server and DB server is on the same machine so I am surprised. It is intermittent. Some days no errors. Some days tons of errors.